# Wordpress Query £ signs failure

Tags: php, wordpress

I have code that takes the name of a term and pulls in a post of a custom post type of the same name. This works well. Except when a £ character is in the title.

e.g. pseudocode

```
$q = new WP_Query (array( 'name' => "Insurance Rating £1K"));
if($q->have_posts()){
    // expected path of logic flow
} else {
    // nothing was found =s
}
```

This post does indeed exist, yet it is not found, and this problem only affects cases with a '£' character in the title. Since Wordpress already sanitizes the titles etc, what is happening? Why does this not work?

edit:

This is a general case, not specific to any codebase of mine. I want to know why this happens and how to avoid it, the codebase this first arose in is irrelevant. So I dont need an alternative solution, as I'm looking for **Why** it happened

edit 2:

The database tables are using `utf8_general_ci` encoding.

The £ character is also being saved as is, not as a html entity, here's a screenshot from phpmyadmin:

[image: Database row]

Comment: Is the pound sign saved in the database as entity (&pound;) or UTF-8?

Comment: its a £ sign in the database, not an entity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What encoding is your PHP file in, and does it match the encoding of the database? They need to match for this to work. (Check your IDE or [this link](http://www.phpwact.org/php/i18n/charsets) provided by @Tom)

Failing that, make sure that the character isn't a `&pound;` entity instead of the literal character.

Comment: There is no £ sign in the php code, this is all done dynamically. The code provided is merely a demonstration

Comment: @Tom then please show the actual code in question. Please when showing pseudo-code instead of the real thing always remember to say so. My third point still stands though - why not use the ID instead? It's much, much safer.

Comment: And indeed it would be nicer to query by ID, but alas, that is not possible. I have a taxonomy term object, and somehow I must retrieve the information post type dynamically for my taxonomy listings. The need arose originally because I cant give a taxonomy term or category a featured image and a truckload of custom attributes

Comment: So quite simply, how would I obtain the ID of the post in question? Given that I have no way of storing it in the taxonomy term. I've already tried assigning the taxonomy term to said post, and the results weren't reliable.

Comment: Anyway, regardless of the rigors of my implementation, that is not what I am curious about. I want to know why this doesn't work, not how do I fix my implementation here. What's to stop the same issue with '£' showing up in a different codebase when using a query?

( I cant show my code )

Comment: @Tom it's probably an encoding issue, with the `£` having a different byte value internally and the query not detecting a match for that reason. Or the pound sign is indeed stored as a HTML entity in the database, although I don't think WP does that.

Comment: Database tables are using utf_general_ci

Comment: @Tom And the encoding of your PHP file is?

Comment: =/ firefox states ISO-8859-1 yet dreamweaver is set to use UTF-8 on all new files

Comment: I've accepted the answer, though maybe make it clearer the encoding of the php file to be precise was the answer? And a reference to http://www.phpwact.org/php/i18n/charsets or better for finding out the encoding of an existing file =]